# Cognito SDK make users filterable for a common property

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-java-2.0

According to the java awssdk [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cognitoidentityprovider/model/ListUsersRequest.html#filter()) it is not possible to filter the userPool for a custom attribute.

Imagine each users belongs to one company. What is the best way to find all users for a company?

I thought about

- storing the companyId in a searchable field e.g. family name.
- Attach user-name|sub|mail of all users to the company and filter the userPool for this attribute. (I have not found documentation for filtering values in a collection, so this might result in many queries)

What is the best way to find all users for a company?